# AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below is the code to upload file to s3 
after upload button is clicked, the error : Uncaught TypeError: AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials is not a constructor.

Please help me understand why is this and how to solve this error.

```js
<html>
<head>
    <title>AWS S3 File Upload</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script> 
  
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
    <button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.region = 'region'; 
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'Id here' 
    });

    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if (err) alert(err);
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
    });

    var bucketName = 'bucket';
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: bucketName
        }
    });

    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
    var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {

        var file = fileChooser.files[0];

        if (file) {

            results.innerHTML = '';
            var objKey = 'testing/' + file.name;
            var params = {
                Key: objKey,
                ContentType: file.type,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };

            bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
                } else {
                    listObjs();
                }
            });
        } else {
            results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
        }
    }, false);
    function listObjs() {
        var prefix = 'testing';
        bucket.listObjects({
            Prefix: prefix
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
            } else {
                var objKeys = "";
                data.Contents.forEach(function(obj) {
                    objKeys += obj.Key + "<br>";
                });
                results.innerHTML = objKeys;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got networking error: network failure at first, later i changed CORS file in the s3 properties which solved from the networking error

**Output: As soon as i launch the HTML page, I am getting an alert message

> ResourceNotFoundException: IdentityPool 'us-east-c:1abadc01-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' not found.
>   After clicking OK on the alert, i am receiving [this error- this link has image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax9Xm.png)

**

Comment: This page works fine for me. although I had to remove the `ACL: 'public-read' bit due to my bucket configuration.  Are you getting this error as soon as the page renders, or when you click upload?  It might help if you update the question with the full output from javascript console.